# Utilizing Spring transactionManager for integration test

Tags: java, spring, spring-test

I've been banging my head against this for a while now & have the sinking feeling I am overlooking something stupid.  I'm trying to use a transaction manager for a very simple integration test, but can't seem to get it to rollback like I think it should.

Class under test:

```
public class JdbcUserDAO implements UserDAO {

@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;

private static final String TERM_USER_SQL =
        "UPDATE USER " +
        "SET TERM_DATE = date('now') " +
        "WHERE USER_NAME = ?";

@Override
public void terminateUser(String userName) {

    try (Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection()){
        PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(TERM_USER_SQL);
        stmt.setString(1, userName);
        stmt.executeUpdate();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Caught SQLException in persistence service", e);
    }
}
```

Spring context (applicationContext.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

<tx:annotation-driven/>
<bean id="userDAO" class="com.mycompany.persistence.dao.impl.JdbcUserDAO"/>
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.sqlite.JDBC"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:sqlite:C:\\development.sqlite3"/>
</bean>
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

Test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"/applicationContext.xml"})
@TransactionConfiguration
@Transactional
public class JdbcUserDAOTest {

    @Autowired
    private UserDAO userDAO;

    @Test
    public void test_terminateUser() {
        userDAO.terminateUser("USERNAME");
    }
}
```

AFAIK, defaultRollback behavior for TransactionConfiguration is "true" and default transactionManager bean name is "transactionManager", so I should be set there.  I run this test and expect the "TERM_DATE" column to revert to "null" (its starting value) after the test completes, but it isn't (I query after the test completes and can see it is still = today's date).

I even get what appears to be very promising-looking logging:

```
Jun 17, 2014 1:25:48 PM org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener startNewTransaction
INFO: Began transaction (1): transaction manager [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager@10279954]; rollback [true]
Jun 17, 2014 1:25:48 PM org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener endTransaction
INFO: Rolled back transaction after test execution for test context [TestContext@41cbd50f testClass = JdbcUserDAOTest, testInstance = com.mycompany.persistence.dao.JdbcUserDAOTest@2d10ed88, testMethod = test_terminateUser@JdbcUserDAOTest, testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@325a92d5 testClass = JdbcUserDAOTest, locations = '{classpath:/applicationContext.xml}', classes = '{}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader', parent = [null]]]
Jun 17, 2014 1:25:48 PM org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext doClose
INFO: Closing org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@3304e92a: startup date [Tue Jun 17 13:25:48 MDT 2014]; root of context hierarchy
```

What the heck am I overlooking???  Many thanks in advance.

If it helps, pertinent POM dependencies look like:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <spring.version>3.2.9.RELEASE</spring.version>
</properties>
```

Comment: Just for fun, are you willing to swap SQLite for H2 or HSQL? I doubt that's the problem, but it can't so any harm to make sure :)

Comment: Funny that you mention that - the real code utilizes Oracle, but I switched to SQLite to take that out of the equation!  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Spring, pleeeeease do **not** write boilerplate JDBC code.

Instead, use Spring's `JdbcTemplate` which automatically works with the current Spring-managed transaction **and** eliminates all boilerplate JDBC code.

You should replace your entire DAO implementation with something like this:

```
public class JdbcUserDAO {

    private static final String TERM_USER_SQL = "UPDATE USER "
            + "SET TERM_DATE = date('now') WHERE USER_NAME = ?";

    private final JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public JdbcUserDAO(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    public void terminateUser(String userName) {
        jdbcTemplate.update(TERM_USER_SQL, userName);
    }

}
```

Regards,

Sam

Comment: Thank you, Sam - you nailed it.  The sad thing is, I really know better than to hand-rolling JDBC, but I really had blinders on.  :(  I took the < 15 minutes to refactor to JdbcTemplate and it worked like a charm.  If anyone is using the above as an example, my finished code looks almost identical to Sam's - the only other thing I changed was getting rid of the "annotation-driven" tag from the context.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Use `DataSourceUtils.getConnection(dataSource)` instead of `dataSource.getConnection()`. The former prepares the connection for transactional support whereas the latter is just bypassing the Spring transactional infrastructure and requires you to handle the transactional details.